# Why don't Conservatives in Washington state try to bar payroll taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, conservatism, washington-state

I read on https://apnews.com/article/initiatives-approved-washington-police-pursuit-income-tax-e5a904bf714083611b67698293c4772b:

> SEATTLE (AP) — Three conservative-backed initiatives that would [do x, y, and] bar an income tax were approved by the Washington state Legislature on Monday.

Why don't Conservatives in Washington state also try to bar payroll taxes? It's rather useless to only bar income taxes since they can be easily recast as payroll taxes, as shown by the recently
established long-term care payroll tax in Washington state.

Comment: Not a full answer, but simplified version because it wouldn't pass, Washington doesn't have income tax, but they already have payroll tax.  Outlawing a tax that doesn't currently exist is possible, outlawing taxes you are currently collecting would be a much more complex solution.  There are also differences in how these taxes are collected and, frankly, they need some kind of tax to pay their expenses, so you can't outlaw every type of tax.

Comment: @dsollen WA has one of the highest budgets per capita among the 50 U.S. states. No further taxes are realistically necessary. It’s all going to bloat, just like in California.

Answer (score -1):

See [9 States without Income Tax](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/taxes/states-with-no-income-tax#:%7E:text=As%20of%202023%2C%20nine%20states,levy%20a%20state%20income%20tax.) for clarification.

You're confusing the WA Cares Fund which is indeed a payroll tax while **still not** an income tax, with an income tax.

### The Reason I'm Answering This Question

Conservatives and Liberals have never disagreed on the fact that funding for government is needed.  What they do disagree on is how to raise funding and how it should be spent.

An income tax taxes everyone, whether they make above the minimum poverty level yearly or millions a year. A payroll tax only taxes those who are working. I'm answering this question as a disabled Texan who chooses to follow the conservative ethic and pick myself up and work so that I don't have to draw from Social Security, which is the federal equivalent of any state funded program.

### Some Example Numbers

I just looked up the population of Washington State which as of 2021 was 7,739,000 (that's 7 million 739 thousand).  Let's assume 75% of them are working citizens.

**7,739,000 x 0.75 = 5,801,250**

That number will fluctuate with population growth.  Babies, Children and disabled citizens, will never be in the 25% because they never work.  Every year, I now have roughly 6 million citizens I can tax without putting an unfair burden on the 25% who have no say in the matter.  On top of that I'm only asking for [58 cents every $100](https://wacaresfund.wa.gov/how-it-works), which is still low enough to please the conservatives and raise money for operational and other expenses, as @dsollen has noted.

**Note that the income tax would tax the entire population, unless exempt**

Think of this from my shoes as a disabled citizen.  If I don't work, is it fair for me to pull money to live on out of a payroll tax when I **did not** contribute to a payroll?  How do we support these citizens without some kind of Tax? A payroll tax is the only way for conservatives to raise money while following the conservative ideal that *Conservatism favors Business*, and the low rate (58 cents/$100) still goes along with the ideal that *Conservatism is Hands-Off with respect to a citizen's money*

I'm pretty sure the state's liberals still don't like the conservative members for other reasons, but I'm certain both sides agree that the state can't operate for free. No conservative believes in no taxes

Conservatives believe lower taxes give citizen's more money.  In turn, those citizens will spend more money, on items like Gas and Groceries where state sales and gas taxes will in turn generate more revenue.  The sales and gas taxes are still really low, but more revenue is generated because more people spend money. A broader example is this:

I can sell 1 Car to 1 person for 5,000 profit or I can sell 500 cars to 500 people for $10 profit.  In the end I still make $5000.  I'm not saying only make $10 a car, I'm saying there are many ways to stimulate economies with low  taxes.

Comment: Except WA already has one of the highest per capita budgets in the U.S. Why can’t it just optimize its current expenses instead of taxing more?

Comment: @JonathanReez Welcome to two-party cooperative government.  Where or what do you optimize/cut?  Washington State does not want to become California.  Who decides what's important and what's not when neither side will cooperate?  Your comment is part of the reason the American Political system is in such a mess, because even at the highest levels both sides refuse to cooperate

Comment: No cooperation = no new expenses = lower taxes = faster growth

Comment: optimizing and government are antonyms. Government agencies have no incentive to optimize, just the opposite. as an official your prestige and often pay depends on the size of your budget and the number of people working for you.  add to that a nearly endless series of regulations you must follow.

Comment: @JonathanReez That's only true in a conservative controlled environment.  Following that theory all the way to the end would lead in a "free" liberal place to live.  You can only squeeze so much blood out of a turnip until there's no blood left.  I.e. if there aren't two parties then we end up with a dictatorship.  It wont matter  that the dictating party is fiscally responsible.  America was founded on the ideal of cooperation, i.e. by cooperating the best bills rise to the top.

Comment: @Jim and success in the private sector is measured by the maximal retention of revenue as profit, which in the context of a monopoly such as with the provision of public services leads to increased cost and reduced quality.  Look at rail in the UK for example.

Comment: @JonathanReez no cooperation also leads to no enforcement (more corruption), no oversight (less planning and more bloat), and budget crises.  The myth of lower taxes leading to faster growth is easily countered by looking at tax rates and growth rates in history.

Comment: @phoog WA already has one of the largest per capita budgets in the U.S. so clearly it’s already one of the most taxed states.